# hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class VS hibernate.transaction.jta.platform

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere

I have this `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class` property in my persistence.xml, Then i have this warning message when running my application.

`Using deprecated org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookup strategy [hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class], use newer org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform strategy instead [hibernate.transaction.jta.platform]`

I don't know what is the different between the 2 properties ? And what is the use of them ?

Could anyone explain the difference and the use of them

I'm using hibernate 4 with websphere 8.5

Answer (score 2):

The `JtaPlatform` offers more transaction-like integrations besides just the transaction manager, notably:

- how to locate transaction manager
- how to user transaction
- how to register transaction synchronization

You can see the full `JtaPlatform` interface on GitHub here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/transaction/jta/platform/spi/JtaPlatform.java

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following:

```
<property name = "hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
```

with

```
<property name = "hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value ="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
```

in the Hibernate configuration/persistence.xml.

Comment: also if you are using an xa-datasource then set transaction-type="JTA" in persistence unit.

Comment: is there a documentation link for the same?